# Teradata - granting access to user table without user being involved

Tags: sql, permissions, teradata

If someone created a table in userspace (e.g. `UD123` with naming convention `EID_table_name`) and that person left the company - is there a way to grant `select` permission to that table to some other user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, DBC should have sufficient access to grant access to another user. If that is not feasible, you can query the DBC.AllRightsV to see who has Grant Authority on the user database and the objects contained within.

```
SELECT *  
  FROM DBC.AllRightsV 
 WHERE DatabaseName = ‘{UserID}’ 
   AND GrantAuthority = ‘Y’;
```